# Why do I have red dots all over my display?

Tags: windows, windows-10, gpu, lenovo-laptop, dual-gpu

I have a Lenovo Y510P laptop that is about 2.5 years old. It has always been fine, though recently it has been getting slow. Suddenly today, there are read dots all over my screen, more or less arranged in vertical lines. It is not my monitor that is the problem, since the red pixels jitter around every time to screen is refreshed by anything. I was playing minecraft, and all was completely fine. When I closed the game, my desktop looked like this, and now everything looks like this.

I have read that this can either be due to a fried GPU, or a bad connection between the GPU and motherboard. I'm only reasking the question, because of muy special circumstance of having a laptop rather than a desktop, and have two graphics cards.

I don't think the connection could've come loose, because in the time that this issue appeared, the laptop hadn't moves at all. How can I investigate further? I'm going to try disabling each GPU one at a time, maybe disable them both if my motherboard has an integrated graphics chip. Restarts do absolutely nothing, so this is a hardware issue (obviously).

Edit: After trying to get to the NVIDIA control panel, I get a message:

> NVIDIA Display settings are not available: You are not currently using a display attached to an NVIDIA GPU

Doesn't this mean that something had to have somehow gone wrong at the exact sae time with *both* of my GPU's?

Edit 2: One of my GPU's displays is disabled in the Device Manager. It gives an error "Code 43", which appears to simply mean that the device is disabled because it gave a message to the CPU indicating that it is not functioning properly.I've tried completely disabling one GPU at a time, then both together, and none of that has made any difference so far. Do I have to restart windows before disabling a device will take effect?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/415993/why-am-i-seeing-red-dots-on-my-lcd-screen?rq=1 in a laptop the dedicated gpu is usually dependant on the on-die gpus frame buffer, which could be why disable does not. .  Could be heat issues , which includes the shared ram or any seperated v-ram.  could be wire issue as seen there.  it is less likely to be software from your desription.

Comment: Why would heat issues randomly start at a specific time one day?

Comment: if it is intermittant you should be able to tell if it was heat, but you also have 2 gpus, could be (dont know) it only kicks in when the dedicated is running, piping data over. the code43 statement is weird, disabling a device should throw no such error, which puts us back at that dependancy on the on-die gpu.  code43 is usually a drivers issue.  Logically if you disabled the dependant screen bufffer gpu and rebooted, the combo setup would not work.   But different laptops apply the 2gpus different (like gamer ones it acts more like seperated card)

Comment: When it is only your OSdesktop that present this issue, then isn't it likely that the on-die gpu is the problem?  Things worked fine when you were on the dedicated, which (should) include the on-die screen buffer. So when processing (not just i/o of the data) the grafics on the on-die the red dots show.  These ram based errors of this type may very well Not go away until the GPU is fully reset, so the time it is seen is only the time they switched gpus.  Full reset of gpu usually means full power down.

Comment: sorry about the read, If you know how to Fully power down the machine, do that,  wait until it is cool, boot it back up, and see if they are there. If it was a ram overheat (or cpu/gpu combo) they wont show up until the overheat occurs again.  If they do show up then do a memtest86 on the boards memory.

Comment: You might try checking the connection anyway for no other reason than to completely rule it out.